# RichMarker not clickable when overlapped by Polygon

Tags: maps, polygon, marker

When a Google Map (API v3) contains a Polygon, Markers placed iside the polygon are clickable but RichMarkers are not. When a RichMarker is clicked, the overlapping Polygon receives the click but not the RichMarker. What am I missing?

Sample code showing a Polygon overlapping a standard Marker and a RichMarker:
http://jsfiddle.net/Hergott/1o15npd6/

```
var PathData = [
[49.2761419673641, -123.118069007778], 
[49.2791259862655, -123.129144031353],
[49.2704849721733, -123.125236002048],
[49.2732990317854, -123.117229946411],
[49.2761419673641, -123.118069007778]
];

function initialize() {

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'));
    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
    var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();

    //original marker
    var point1 = new google.maps.LatLng(49.272238, -123.122482);
    var marker1 = new google.maps.Marker({ position: point1, map: map,  title: 'Original marker' });
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker1, 'click', function() {
        infowindow.setContent(this.title);
        infowindow.open(map, this);
    });
    bounds.extend(point1);

    //RichMarker
    var point2 = new google.maps.LatLng(49.277, -123.125);
    var RichMarkerDiv='<div style="width:100px; height:100px;border:solid black 1px;">RichMarker</div>';
    var marker2 = new RichMarker({ position: point2, map: map,  title: 'RichMarker', content: RichMarkerDiv });
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker2, 'click', function() {
        infowindow.setContent(this.title);
        infowindow.open(map, this);
    });
    bounds.extend(point2);

    //polygon
    var path = [];
    for (var i in PathData) {
        var p = PathData[i];
        var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(p[0], p[1]);
        path.push(latlng);
        bounds.extend(latlng);
    }
    var poly = new google.maps.Polygon({ paths: path, strokeColor: '#FF0000', strokeWeight: 3, fillColor: '#FF0000', fillOpacity: 0.1 });
    poly.setMap(map);
    google.maps.event.addListener(poly, 'click', function() {
        infowindow.setContent('Polygon clicked');
        infowindow.open(map, this);
    });    

    //fit map
    map.fitBounds(bounds);
}

initialize();
```

Comment: I have fixed the jsfiddle link.

Answer (score 1):

Found the problem:
the RichMarker did receive the click but since it is not passing the event to the event handler, it propagated to the Polygon and the Polygon received the click too.

Solution: 
1. fix the incorrect event handling in RichMarker.js, lines 731-733 change to 
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(this.markerContent_, 'click', function(e) {
      google.maps.event.trigger(that, 'click', e);
    });

1. the click listener for RichMarker now receives the event handle and uses it to stop propagation
   google.maps.event.addListener(marker2, 'click', function(e) {
       infowindow.setContent('RichMarker clicked');
       infowindow.open(map, this);
       e.stopPropagation();
   });

Comment: `e.stopPropagation();` gives error in IE. Have you checked on IE ?